# VB.NET add a decimal Point to Series

Tags: vb.net, charts, format, decimal

The following Function creates multiple series for a graph.

```
Function createSeries(ByVal fileNames() As String, ByVal intValXAxis As Integer, ByVal intValYAxis As Integer) As Series()
    Dim ChartSeries(fileNames.Count) As Series
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each filename In fileNames
        ChartSeries(i) = New Series
        ChartSeries(i).ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine
        ChartSeries(i).ChartArea = "ChartArea1"
        If filename.Contains("NOK") = True Then
            ChartSeries(i).Color = Color.Red
            ChartSeries(i).BorderWidth = 3
        Else
            ChartSeries(i).Color = Color.Green
        End If

        Dim fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(filename)
        Do

            Dim strCache() As String = Split(fileReader.ReadLine(), ";")
            ChartSeries(i).Points.AddXY(strCache(intValXAxis - 1), strCache(intValYAxis - 1))

            ChartSeries(i).ToolTip = filename
        Loop Until fileReader.EndOfStream = True
        i += 1
    Next
    Return ChartSeries
End Function
```

The problem I have is, that the Y-Values of the Series I create are mostly something like that: 0,09440104 or 0,1757813.  I need these Values shown on the graph as they are, but the zero's got removed and the Y-Point-Values are : 9440104 or 1757813

I tried to format them with "Globalization" before adding them to the Series, but it doesn't solved the problem.

Just to be clear: I want the numbers as shown above(0,09440104 and 0,1757813) to be the Y-values of the points.

How can i solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `En-US` culture will read your comma `","` as thousand separator and thus taking your data as `> 0` rather than  `< 0`.

You have two options: change the culture or change the string format. If all your numbers are less than `1000` (or, to be more precise, not having `.` as thousand separator), I recommend simply to replace `,` with `.`

```
Dim strCache() As String = Split(fileReader.ReadLine(), ";")
Dim repStrX = strCache(intValXAxis - 1).Replace(",",".")
Dim repStrY = strCache(intValYAxis - 1).Replace(",",".")
ChartSeries(i).Points.AddXY(repStrX , repStrY)
```

Or, if they are having value more than `1000` (or, again, to be more precise, not having `.` as thousand separator), without specifying the culture, you could also use `Replace` with some tricks: making use of non-existing character as intermediate value to flip between `.` and `,` in the original `string`.

```
Dim strCache() As String = Split(fileReader.ReadLine(), ";")
Dim repStrX = strCache(intValXAxis - 1).Replace(",","G").Replace(".",",").Replace("G",".")
Dim repStrY = strCache(intValYAxis - 1).Replace(",","G").Replace(".",",").Replace("G",".")
ChartSeries(i).Points.AddXY(repStrX , repStrY)
```

Comment: Unfortunately they aren't all under 1000, so I have to change the culture?

Comment: @flohdieter how are they written when they are not under 1000? do they use `.`? example: `11.123,7410`

Comment: The following is a sample dataset of how I receive them: 0,02500317;99,96948;108;0,1464844;0,15625;-0,02709161;10,75;0,1037598;0;0;-0,004882813 // each value is seperated with a semicolon and the user can choose which two values are shown in the graph.

Comment: @flohdieter OK, as long as they are not written with `.` (dot), you could use the first option. I see no `.` (dot) in your data, then simply use `Replace(",",".")`

Comment: Yes, the first solution work very fine for me, thanks a lot :) edit: i can't see the "V" :/

Comment: @flohdieter great, you learn fast! ;) welcome to stack overflow and see you around!

Comment: thank you for the little tutorial on how to deal with answers :) Hope we will see us again :)